# Tangent developable of helix.

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $T$ be union of tangent lines to helix $C=(\cos x, \sin x,x)$.

1) I want to prove that $T - C$ is a smooth manifold and find equation for $T$.

2) I want to find how many times a line can intersect $T$.

T is parameterized by $\phi:(t,s) \mapsto (\cos t -s \sin t, \sin t +s \cos t, t+s).$ To prove that $T-C$ is a smooth manifold I need to show that $\phi$ is embedding and $\phi_s(t,s)$ and $\phi_t(t,s)$ are linearly independent for $s>0$. I can't prove that $\phi$ is embedding. And I don't know how can I find equation for $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrization $\phi$ is continuous and smooth in 3-space embeddable.

The developable helicoid has zero Gaussian curvature when the $ z = s+t \ne 0 $  in parametrization. So is the case when it is flat with $s+t$ zero. They are both two dimensional surfaces embeddable in 3D.

Both the surfaces are built on two parameters $t,s$.

[image]

They are *isometrically equivalent,*  mappable bijectively, ie., both ways.

For tangents consider between two $s$ values, infinitely many in the $s$ interval at any $ (t=t_1)$

For helices, any $ (s = s_1)$  value with two limiting $t$ values of rotation  infinitely many in the $t$ interval

Do you have these questions with respect to the flat spiral?